# docker-compose up command with non default file name, how does it work?

Tags: docker-compose

I have two files `docker-compose-dapr.yml` and `docker-compose-infra.yml` files.

Basically I am trying to [run this example](https://github.com/cecilphillip/ZeroToHeroDaprCon/tree/main/demo2).

First I ran this command

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-infra.yml up -d
```

It built, and some containers are ready.

Next I ran simply the up command.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Things work as expected.

The question is which files does `docker-compose up` command pick up. Both?

As per my earlier understanding, if the file name is something non-default, then we need to explicitly specify using the -f. But here I am not specifying any file, so which files is it picking?

Comment: Do you have docker-compose.yaml at any parent folder?

Comment: No. Its just that folder. You can take a look at [that folder](https://github.com/cecilphillip/ZeroToHeroDaprCon/tree/main/demo2).

Comment: I am asking because according to docker-compose reference it is looking for the default file at the working folder and traverses to **parent** folders as well. So I assumed that you probably have some high-level folder that contains `docker-compose.yml` or `docker-compose.override.yml`

Comment: No. I dont have other files. Just those files mentioned. I am aware of docker-compose.yml and docker-compose.override.yml files. And thats the reason, I am bit puzzled, how it is working.